# Error handling in EventSource

Tags: java, javascript, html, event-sourcing, server-sent-events

I'm trying to make a page that uses the EvenSource object (in javascript) to make an Server-Sent Event (comet).
I read many tutorials about it and haven't found one that explains the following questions:

1. When i subscribe to the "onerror" event of the EventSource - what is the type of the parameter i get? How do i know exactly what was the error?
2. I know that EvenSource has a readystate and that it changes depend on the browser. Why is my readystate changes to 0 after each "onmessage" event occurs? (i use chrome).
3. How do i prove that my connection to the server stays connected and not reconnect every time?

Browser: Chrome.

Server Side: Java (if it's relevant the example i made is in Java EE preview. **But i'm going to work on WebLogic 10R3.**

What happens in my example is that the data is being sent from the server to the client, than the "onerror" event occurs (readystate is 0) and after 3 seconds (default for chrome) it reconnects and sends the data again.

The javascript code:

```
var source = new EventSource("TrySRV");
source.onmessage = function(event){
    alert(event.data);
}

source.onerror = function(event){
    alert(source.readystate);
}
```

The Java code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.getWriter.write("Hello World");
```

If there's anything else missing that you wish to know - tell me.
Hope you'll be able to help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to hold the connection on server, instead of responsing on it and closing.

Please see http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315, or Glassfish / Grizzly / Jetty servers.

Answer (score 1):

try using:

`response.getWriter.write("data:Hello World")`

According to w3schools: Output the data to send (Always start with "data: ")

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp